# How to Save Image attachement from Mobile App - Using WCF Rest Service

Tags: wcf, rest, mobile-application, save-image

In my WCF Service I will receive an image attachment from a mobile App. I dont know how to write the code. I appreciate if you can forward some examples and code. I am new to WCF.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/SaveAttachment",
              Method = "POST",
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ReturnSaveAttacmentStatus SaveAttachment(DomainName,TimeSheetID, ImageFIle);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at [here](https://github.com/sakirayan78/AndroidWcfImageUpload) on the git hub which I have written an application that how to upload images from android phone to wcf service with the sample application